# Hacer aplicaciones QT para 64 bits

Tags: c++, qt, qt-creator

tengo una duda, estoy experimentando con Qt C++ y me descargué el Qt Creator desde el instalador online recomendado. Al principio no instale MinGW, por lo que fue un parto a la hora de configurar el compilador, desistí, instalé MinGW y el QTCreator me reconoció el kit como `Desktop QT 5.9.1 MinGW 32 bits`, y salió andando. Pero, que sigifica esto? Que solo puedo hacer aplicaciones de 32 bits? En ese caso, como puedo compilar una aplicación de 64 bits, utilizando un compilador 64 bits que no sea Microsoft Visual C++ Compiler (que desde VS me funcionaba de 10, pero desde QT creator es imposible que funcione)?

Espero haber sid claro. Desde ya muchas gracias

Comment: No olvides validar y votar la respuesta correcta.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Qt te proporciona sus librerías compiladas para un catálogo determinado de compiladores. Si necesitas trabajar con un compilador diferente (y los binarios no son compatibles con el mismo) entonces tendrás que compilar a mano Qt con el nuevo compilador (lo cual es un proceso laborioso tanto por cosillas a configurar como por tiempo)... pero no es imposible.

Lo que puedes hacer es revisar la herramienta de mantenimiento de Qt ya que ahí encontrarás, para la versión de Qt con la que vas a trabajar, algunos kits basados en msvc... descárgate uno de esos compiladores e instala el kit correspondiente así como la versión de Qt compilada con dicho compilador.

Por poner un ejemplo, la versión 5.9.1 dispone de montajes en 64 bits para:

- msvc 2013
- msvc 2015
- msvc 2017

Supongamos que dispones (o puedes conseguir) el compilador msvc 2015... lo que tendrías que instalar entonces es:

- cerrar QtCreator (importante)
- instalar el compilador
- instalar Qt 5.9.1 -> msvc2015 64-bit (desde la herramienta de mantenimiento)

Comment: Gracias por responder! Mañana me fijo bien eso del msvc y aviso. Si sigo usando MinGW de 32 bits solo me va a permitir compilar aplicaciones de 32 o el compilador no tiene nada que ver con la arquitectura del sistema a compilar?

Comment: @Genarito mingw 32 crea binarios de 32 bits, mientras que mingw64 crea binarios en 64

Comment: Gracias! Una última consulta si no es mucha molestia,, si consigo e instalo el compilador msvc 2015 como dijiste, ¿que es lo que estoy instalando desde la herramienta de mantenimiento? ¿Un conector? ¿Drivers?

Comment: @Genarito la librería de qt compilada con ese compilador, lo que te da unas librerías compatibles con el compilador

Comment: Sos un crack! Mil gracias!